# How can I fix a monitor that suddenly got blurry?

Tags: display, lcd

I just got an unexpected missing-required-file error when compiling a program and decided to reboot.  After rebooting, my primary monitor — I have a two-monitor setup — became blurry.

The display has been working fine for almost a year, and I did not make any changes to its configuration recently.  In particular, I did not change the video card, resolution or refresh rate.  It's an LCD, so degaussing isn't the solution.  I have confirmed that it is set to the recommended resolution and refresh rate.  The only non-blurry thing is the OSD; even the Windows XP boot screen is blurry.  The second monitor in my display, which is the same model and is attached to the same video card, is still working fine.

How can I restore crispness to my monitor?

EDIT:
Yes, the BIOS screen is blurry as well.  As far as I know, no unusual events, such as booting into safe mode, have occurred recently.  The connection is DVI.  Will update later with the results of switching the monitors, can't do it right now.

Comment: Some more information that may help: Is the BIOS display before you boot Windows blurry? Even if you didn't change your configuration, maybe something changed the resolution in Windows (e.g. a boot in safe mode), is this the case? Do you use a VGA or DVI connection? What happens if you swap the monitors?

Comment: Try using a different DVI cable... maybe the current cable is bad or is not fully in.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check that all the wires are connected properly, try re-plugging every connection. If that fails, try a different cable and a different computer - that should give you some idea of where the problem is (screen DVI port, DVI cable, or computer DVI port).

From the information you provided, it seems unlikely that it's a problem with the computer's software or the screen's electronics.

Comment: I will try jiggling the wires.  Unfortunately I don't have other cables or computers available to play with, as I'm asking about my work computer.

Comment: Yeah, it worked.  I must have managed to kick something loose at exactly the same moment I was rebooting.

Comment: Same thing happened to me! I was about to dump the monitor, but moving the VGA cable fixed it.

Comment: I thought I was going blind suddenly. A little jiggle went a long way.

Answer (score 3):

If you boot to a [Linux LiveCD](http://www.livecdlist.com/) like [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) or [Knoppix](http://www.knoppix.net/), is the display crisp? If so, it's probably a software problem within windows. if not, it's probably a hardware issue.

Comment: Not an option; this is a work computer.  Good answer other than that, though.

Comment: The fact that it was also blurry in the BIOS indicates a hardware issue.

Comment: That edit was posted after I answered the question, so I feel your downvote is unfair. I feel answer is technically correct and is a useful way of troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

WiFi radio interference from laptop and tablet into DP cable was doing it to me...
I was going crazy wondering why my text became fuzzy again!!!